# Composable lambda not memoized?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to understand how lambda memoization works in compose compiler: [ComposerLambdaMemoization](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/compose-compiler-1.6.21/compose/compiler/compiler-hosted/src/main/java/androidx/compose/compiler/plugins/kotlin/lower/ComposerLambdaMemoization.kt). From what I understand, for non composable lambdas the compiler will wrap the lambda with `remember` call if the lambda only captures stable values. However, it seems that this remember wrapping is only for non composable lambdas. For composable lambdas, the compose compiler will create a synthetic class `ComposableLambdaImpl` and remember the `ComposableLambdaImpl` class. However kotlin still allocate a new instance of lambda and call `ComposableLambdaImpl.update` with the actual lambda: [ComposableLambda](https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/compose-compiler-1.6.21/compose/runtime/runtime/src/jvmMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/internal/ComposableLambda.jvm.kt#L93). Since two different lambda instance are never equal, `ComposableLambdaImpl.update` will always invalidate recompose scopes that invoke the composable lambda.

To validate my assumption, I wrote the following code:

```
class ComposableLambdaActivity : ComponentActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            val staticHeader = "Should composable lamdba be remembered?"
            val counter = remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
            val counterValue = counter.intValue
            LambdaMemoization(
                onClicked = { counter.intValue += 1 },
                header = {
                    Text(text = staticHeader)
                    Log.e("ComposableLambdaTest", "Header recomposed!")
                }
            ) {
                Text(text = "Clicked $counterValue times!")
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun LambdaMemoization(
    onClicked: () -> Unit,
    header: @Composable () -> Unit,
    body: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    Log.e("ComposableLambdaTest", buildString {
        append("onClicked: ${onClicked}@${onClicked.hashCode()}\n")
        append("header: ${header}\n")
        append("body: ${body}\n")
    })
    Column {
        header()
        Button(onClick = { onClicked() }) {
            body()
        }
    }
}
```

After clicking the button several times, the "Header recomposed" message is printed several times, even though it only reads a static string which it captures. I think the compose compiler generated some code like this:

```
setContent {
    val staticHeader = "Should composable lamdba be remembered?"
    val counter = remember { mutableIntStateOf(0) }
    val counterValue = counter.intValue
    val nonComposableLambdaOnClick = remember(counter.intValue) {{ counter.intValue += 1 }}
    val composableLambdaHeader = {
        Text(text = staticHeader)
        Log.e("ComposableLambdaTest", "Header recomposed!")
    }
    val wrappedComposableLambdaHeader = remember {
        ComposableLambdaImpl(key, true, composableLambdaHeader)
    }
    wrappedComposableLambdaHeader.update(composableLambdaHeader)

    val composableLambdaBody = {
        Text(text = "Clicked $counterValue times!")
    }
    val wrappedComposableLambdaBody = remember {
        ComposableLambdaImpl(key, true, composableLambdaBody)
    }
    wrappedComposableLambdaBody.update(composableLambdaBody)
    LambdaMemoization(
        onClicked = nonComposableLambdaOnClick,
        header = wrappedComposableLambdaHeader,
        body = wrappedComposableLambdaBody
    )
}
```

Note that the `composableLambdaHeader` and `composableLambdaBody` are not remembered so they will be recreated every time. So my question is, why doesn't compose compiler use a remember to wrap them just like what the compiler does for non composable lambdas?